# Unsubscribe in Observable KnockOutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

Im currently using KnockOut JS and i conducted some research about when the observable is notified it will fire a function which is like this

```
function FunctionToSubscribe()
{

}

var TestObservable = ko.observableArray([]);

TestObservable.subscribe(FunctionToSubscribe);
```

i am subscribing `FunctionToSubscribe` in this event

im currently thinking is there a way to unsubscribe it? like we do in c#? when unsubscribing events anyone have an idea regarding this???

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `subscribe` function returns the "subscription" object which has a `dispose` method what you can use to unsubscribe:

```
var TestObservable = ko.observableArray([]);

var subscription = TestObservable.subscribe(FunctionToSubscribe);

//call dispose when you want to unsubscribe
subscription.dispose();
```

See also in the documentation: [Explicitly subscribing to observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables)

Comment: Is there a way to check if subscription has been disposed?

Comment: @burktelefon The subscription object does not have a public API to check that it has has been dispose.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dispose` method.

```
function FunctionToSubscribe()
{

}

var TestObservable = ko.observableArray([]);

// subscribe
var subscriber = TestObservable.subscribe(FunctionToSubscribe);

// unsubscribe
subscriber.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to temporarily pause the subscription and do some work so I ended up doing this:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.suspendableSubscribe = function (callback, callbackTarget, event) {
    var isSuspended = false;
    return ko.utils.extend(this.subscribe(function () {
        if (!isSuspended)
            return callback.apply(this, arguments);
    }, callbackTarget, event), {
        suspend: function () { isSuspended = true; },
        resume: function () { isSuspended = false; }
    });
};
```

**Usage**

```
var name = ko.observable('CodingYoshi');
var subscription = name.suspendableSubscribe(function(){ // code... });
subscription.suspend();
name('CodingYoshi2');
subscription.resume();
```